# Show that this equation together with the boundary conditions $u(0) = 2, u(\pi) = 0$ has no solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ordinary differential equation: $u'' + u = 0$.

I have no idea how to solve this, no idea what so ever. Please help.

Comment: So you do not know that the general solution is $A\sin x+B\cos x$?

Comment: Hint: try going around in circles.

Comment: r^2 + r =0 implies r(r+1) = 0 implies r=0 and r=-1 so the general solution is A + Be^-x =0 ? isnt that the general solution and cos and sin are only used for complex solutions

Comment: The equation you want to solve is $r^2+1=0$, the $r$ term is reserved for the first derivative (there is none). So you get combos of $e^{ix}$ and $^{-ix}$ which lead to sines and cosines for real solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic solution of ODE given is $u=c_1 sinx+c_2cosx$.

Put the boundary conditions in , to get $u(0)=c_2=2$ , $u(\pi)=-c_2=0$

$c_2$ is a constant , can't have two different values.

Hence, there is no solution.

Comment: r^2 + r =0 implies r(r+1) = 0 implies r=0 and r=-1 so the general solution is A + Be^-x =0 ? isnt that the general solution and cos and sin are only used for complex solutions

Comment: $u'' \rightarrow r^2 , \ u \rightarrow 1 \Rightarrow r^2 + 1 =0 \Rightarrow r= \pm i$